# WP7 Passing XML Data Between Pages

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

just need some guidance. lemme post the codes first:

XAML:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Name="subjectBlock" Text="{Binding SubjectName}" FontSize="26" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Tap="subjectBlock_Tap" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LecturerName}" FontSize="24" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
            <TextBlock Text=" "/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

C# code:

```
XDocument xmlCourse = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

var xmlData = from subject in xmlCourse.Descendants("subject")
              select new Subject
              {
                  SubjectID    = subject.Element("subjectID").Value,
                  SubjectName  = subject.Element("subjectName").Value,
                  LecturerName = subject.Element("lecturerName").Value
              };

subjectList.ItemsSource = xmlData;

xmlFile.Close();
```

...

```
private void subjectBlock_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{            
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/eIICS;component/Pages/Coursework.xaml?type=2&subject=" + subjectid, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

im trying to pass the SubjectID to another page via the tapped event. im pulling the data via xml, each individual Subject has an ID and im wondering if there is a way to pass that ID directly/indirectly?

but i cant seem to wrap my head around it just yet.

some guidance would be really nice. thanks. just starting out on WP7 myself.

cheers.

Comment: Check this http://innovativesingapore.com/2010/09/code-how-to-store-data-and-pass-data-in-windows-phone/

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have implemented so far, the easiest way is to retrieve the data context from the textblock object and pass it to the next page.  Adding to the handler you wrote above:

```
private void subjectBlock_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
  var textblock = sender as TextBlock;
  if(null != textblock) {
      var subject = textblock.DataContext as Subject;
      if(null != subject) {
        string subjectid = subject.SubjectID;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/eIICS;component/Pages/Coursework.xaml?type=2&subject=" + subjectid, UriKind.Relative));
      }
    }
```

However, I also want to note that this might not be the best solution.  Using event handlers to handle all user interactions might make your code hard to maintain overtime, and it is really hard to write test cases for event handlers.  You can consider using MVVM frameworks like MVVMLight to help improve the testibility of your code.  The framework comes with a commanding system that de-couples the view (XAML) from the code (.cs).  It will save you a lot of headaches down the road =)

Link to the MVVMLight project: http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/

A post on the commanding framework: http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/26/using-relaycommands-in-silverlight-and-wpf.aspx

Comment: for some reason sender.DataContext does not read. i think its an issue with my XAML, correct?

Comment: Sorry about that it's an issue with the code.  Updated the code it should work now

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. Thanks to Leo Tse for giving me pointers. I searched more and I found this - http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/windows/windows-phone-7-silverlight-tutorial/

Since I was using a ListBox and I just wanted to pass on the SubjectID. Using ListBox.SelectedItem as an object worked well. Though I'm not sure if this is hacky but it seems right.

```
private void subjectBlock_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{   
    var subject = subjectList.SelectedItem as Subject;
    if (null != subject) 
    {
        string subjectid = subject.SubjectID;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/eIICS;component/Pages/Coursework.xaml?type=2&subjectid=" + subjectid, UriKind.Relative));
    } 
}
```

Still learning WP7. Its been blast so far!

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  Make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that other may learn from your success.  Cheers~